# Filtrar datos de la tabla antes de hacer el Left Join

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2008

Se me ha presentado un caso que no se como resolver, estoy intentando filtrar ciertos datos de varias tablas, en este caso pondré solamente una muestra del caso de uso que no se como resolver.

Tabla `ESTATUSEMPLEADO` : (Tiene muchos mas campos, solo es una muestra)

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ Codigo   ║ Nombre║ .... ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬══════╣     
║ 1        ║ Juan  ║ .... ║
║ 2        ║ José  ║ .... ║
║ 3        ║ Maria ║ .... ║
║ 4        ║ Joel  ║ .... ║
║ 5        ║ Ramón ║ .... ║
║ 6        ║ Teresa║ .... ║
║ ....     ║ ....  ║ .... ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

Tabla `NOTIFICACION`: (En esta el campo `Codigo` se puede repetir, es una tabla de Detalles...)

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦═══════╦════════════╗ 
║ Codigo   ║ Estado║ UserN ║ OtroCampo  ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 4        ║ N     ║ admin ║ Dato1      ║
║ 1        ║ S     ║ admin ║ Dato2      ║
║ 6        ║ N     ║ admin ║ Dato3      ║
║ 1        ║ N     ║ otro  ║ Dato4      ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

---

```
SELECT e.Codigo, e.Nombre,
       Leida = case when n.Estado = 'S' then 'S' else 'N' end,
       n.OtroCampo,
FROM ESTATUSEMPLEADO e 
LEFT JOIN NOTIFICACION n  
ON e.Codigo = n.Codigo AND n.UserN = 'admin' AND n.Estado in('N')
WHERE e.AlgunCampo = ....
```

Resultado deseado:

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦═══════╦════════════╗ 
║ Codigo   ║ Nombre  ║ Leida ║ OtroCampo  ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ 2        ║ José    ║ N     ║ NULL       ║
║ 3        ║ Maria   ║ N     ║ NULL       ║
║ 4        ║ Joel    ║ N     ║ Dato1      ║
║ 5        ║ Ramón   ║ N     ║ NULL       ║
║ 6        ║ Teresa  ║ N     ║ Dato3      ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

Con este select me esta mostrando todos los datos de la tabla `ESTATUSEMPLEADO` el filtro del `UserN` funciona correctamente, cuando también quiero filtrar por el `Estado` no filtra los datos correctamente, debe excluirme el `Codigo = 1` ya que estoy filtrando que el `Estado = 'N'` en cambio me lo está mostrando en el resultado y me muestra el campo `Leida = 'N'`.

> - No estoy usando WHERE para filtrar la tabla `NOTIFICACION` debido a que esta tabla puede o no contener registros, y si lo realizo en el Where, solo me mostrará los datos que se encuentren en esta tabla.
> - WHERE e.AlgunCampo = .... (Esto es porque también tengo algunas condiciones pero pertenecientes a la tabla `ESTATUSEMPLEADO`)
> - Utilizo `n.Estado in('N')` ya que hay momentos en que tengo que filtar los `S` y `N`.

Deseo obtener todos los datos de la tabla `ESTATUSEMPLEADO` y hacer la unión izquierda con la tabla `NOTIFICACION`, para filtrar los datos y que solo me muestre los datos que cumplan con las condiciones especificadas.

**Entorno:** SQL Server 2008 R2

*Si mi pregunta no es del todo clara, por favor plantear las dudas en los comentarios. Gracias.*

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No, esto no me muestra los datos correctamente, no me muestra los demás campos de la tabla `ESTATUSEMPLEADO`

Comment: Entonces tal vez lo que te falte es considerar que `Estado` puede llegar a ser `NULL`, prueba con `Leida = case when isnull(n.Estado, 'N') = 'S' then 'S' else 'N' end`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, tampoco me funciona esta manera, he modificado mi pregunta agregando el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo así:

```
SELECT  e.Codigo, 
        e.Nombre,
        Leida = case when n.Estado = 'S' then 'S' else 'N' end,
         n.OtroCampo
    FROM ESTATUSEMPLEADO e 
    LEFT JOIN NOTIFICACION n  
        ON e.Codigo = n.Codigo 
        AND n.UserN = 'admin' 
    WHERE isnull(n.Estado, 'N') = 'N'
```

Llevamos el filtro de estado al `where` y consideramos los eventuales `NULL` por inexistencia de filas en `NOTIFICACION` como `N`

Comment: Esto es justo como lo deseo, funciona bien. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Para tratar comparaciones del conjunto de la derecha puedes implementar explicitamente que el campo sea is null.

```
SELECT E.Codigo
 , E.Nombre
 , ISNULL(N.ESTADO,'N') as Leída
 , N.OTROCAMPO as OtroCampo
FROM estatusEmpleado E
 LEFT JOIN NOTIFICACION N ON E.Codigo = N.CODIGO
   WHERE 
        (N.USERN = 'ADMIN'
         OR N.USERN IS NULL)
     AND
        (N.ESTADO = 'N'
         OR N.ESTADO IS NULL);
```

Comment: También es una opción, gracias por el aporte.