# Filtro entre dos tablas en slq server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola amigos antes que nada gracias por su apoyo, tengo una duda acerca de como implementar una consulta que pueda solucionar el siguiente problema, tengo una tabla A y una tabla B, en la tabla A tengo un campo llamado clave el cual al ser llenado mediante una serie de validaciones puede o no ser insertado también en la tabla B, actualmente necesito saber cuales es la lista de registro que no sean insertados en la tabla B, este problema lo he solventado de momento seleccionando todos los registro de A y buscarlo en el tabla B esto a nivel código en C# y con el uso de foreach y if pero el problema es que esto me consume demasiados recursos y tiempo.

Comment: Busca ejemplos para `EXCEPT`, `NOT IN` o `NOT EXISTS`. Fuera de eso, tu pregunta es muy amplia para poder contestarla.

Comment: Agrega tu codigo. Clarifica tu problema con un ejemplo practico.

Comment: Aunque no esta claro lo que preguntas, puedes ver [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/317041/69447) pienso que puede darte una idea de como lograr lo que quieres o al menos, realizar la pregunta un poco mas clara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas la solución a mi problema fue la siguiente estructura de una consulta `SELECT * FROM TABLA_A WHERE CLAVE NOT IN (SELECT CLAVE_ALTERNA FROM TABLA_B)` es básicamente eso Gracias.

Comment: Por favor cuando te sea posible no olvides marcar como aceptada tu respuesta